# random's choice function is giving an unexpected error

Tags: python, random

```
import random
names_list = []
emails_list = []
original_dict = {}
assigned_dict = {}
emails_list2 = emails_list

# ------------------------ Saving Data -------------------------- #
while True:
    name = str(input("Enter your name: "))
    if name == "e":
        break
    email = str(input(f"Enter {name}'s email: "))
    if email == "e":
        break
    original_dict[name] = email

# ------------------------ Assigning Data -------------------------- #

for each_name in names_list:
    chosen_email = random.choice(emails_list2)
    print(chosen_email)
    assigned_dict[each_name] = chosen_email

print(names_list)
print(emails_list)
print(random.choice(emails_list))
print(original_dict)
print(assigned_dict)
```

---

Above is my whole code...
the problem is that when I type `random.choice([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])` I am able to get a desired result as it gives me a random item from the list. But when I type `random.choice(emails_list2)` it is not giving me desired output. Instead it's giving an error which is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hp\PycharmProjects\SecretSanta_Program\main.py", line 36, in <module>
    print(random.choice(emails_list))
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\random.py", line 346, in choice
    return seq[self._randbelow(len(seq))]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

What can I do to get a random item from the list called `emails_list2`?

I was expecting a number of outcomes including a random item from the
`emails_list` list.

Comment: The lists are empty. You only put data in the dict.

Comment: You may want to use `random.shuffle` instead if you want to avoid repeats.

Comment: Using "e" to exit is weird. It would seem more natural to exit on empty input.

Comment: @KellyBundy No. What I mean is that *IndexError: list index out of range* will not be emitted by the code shown in the question. At least, not with Python 3.12.1

Comment: @CtrlZ Their output shows they used Python 3.9, which I think does show their message.

Comment: I don't know what are you trying to do when you assign `emails_list2 = emails_list`, but it's likely not doing what you think. [How do I clone a list so that it doesn't change unexpectedly after assignment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802)

Comment: Please post a [mre]. For example, all the `-- Saving Data --` section doesn't seem relevant to your problem, and forces to manually enter two inputs per debugging iteration. [ask].

Comment: From [`random.choice` documentation (python 3.9)](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/random.html#random.choice): _Return a random element from the non-empty sequence seq. If seq is empty, raises IndexError._

Comment: You can (and should) populate your `email_list` like this: `email_list = list(original_dict.values())`

Answer (score 1):

When I run your code I get the error `IndexError('Cannot choose from an empty sequence')`. I am not sure how you got the error `IndexError: list index out of range`, since your list `emails_list` is empty, i.e. contains no elements.

The code in your `for` loop is never executed, since `names_list` is also an empty array, so it has no elements to iterate over. If you want to select a random email from the ones the user entered you first need to save the emails in the appropriate lists:

```py
while True:
    name = str(input("Enter your name: "))
    if name == "e":
        break
    names_list.append(name) 
    email = str(input(f"Enter {name}'s email: "))
    if email == "e":
        break
    emails_list.append(email)
    original_dict[name] = email
```

Now I get this output:

```
Enter your name: test
Enter test's email: test-email
Enter your name: hello
Enter hello's email: hello-email
Enter your name: world
Enter world's email: world-email
Enter your name: e
hello-email
world-email
world-email
['test', 'hello', 'world']
['test-email', 'hello-email', 'world-email']
world-email
{'test': 'test-email', 'hello': 'hello-email', 'world': 'world-email'}
{'test': 'hello-email', 'hello': 'world-email', 'world': 'world-email'}
```

Since we now added the data entered by the user to the lists, choosing a random element from the list works.